# Hierarchical dependency issue on Maven Build

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot, apache-kafka

This is the error I have when building my Maven Project.

Source of project: [Project](https://dzone.com/articles/developing-async-microservices-architecture-using), [Github link](https://github.com/ayman-elgharabawy/Kafka-SpringBoot-WebSocket)

Setup: Eclipse IDE on Windows.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project uicontroller-service: Could not resolve dependencies for project poc.microsvc-angular:uicontroller-service:jar:0.1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at poc.microsvc-angular:microservice-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:jar:0.8.2.1 -> org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6 -> org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.21: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.21: Could not transfer artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:pom:1.7.21 from/to public (https://globalrepository.mclocal.int/artifactory/public): connect timed out -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]

Here is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>poc.microsvc-angular</groupId>
<artifactId>uicontroller-service</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <docker.plugin.version>0.3.258</docker.plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>poc.microsvc-angular</groupId>
        <artifactId>microservice-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>microsvc-angular/${project.name}</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                <skipDockerBuild>false</skipDockerBuild>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Is there a chance of corrupted jars or is it something else?

Comment: The connection has timed out, I'm guessing you need to set a proxy in your settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your local `~/.m2/settings.xml` or `C:\Users\myUserName\.m2\settings.xml` for windows has configuration to point to a corporate /internal mirror of maven central. You can temporarily remove this potentially to fix your issue.